# Angular 4 file upload with rest easy jax rs java ee

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I am trying to upload an image to a server using Angular as the front end and java ee web service jax rs rest easy as my back end. This my code for the angular/front end:

HTML page:

```
<md-card>
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" placeholder="Upload          
files" >

</md-card>
```

**For the component:**

```
fileChange(event) {
let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
let fileListLength = fileList.length;
if(fileListLength > 0) {
    let formData:FormData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < fileListLength; i++) {
    formData.append("uploadFile[]", fileList[i]);
}

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/BCWEB/uploadProdImage", formData, 
options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
    .subscribe(
         data => console.log('success'),
         error => console.log(error)
    )}
}
For the backend java ee restful web service:

String[] contentDispositionHeader = headers.getFirst("Content-
Disposition").split(";");

for (String name : contentDispositionHeader) {

    if ((name.trim().startsWith("filename"))) {

        String[] tmp = name.split("=");

        String fileName = tmp[1].trim().replaceAll("\"","");

        return fileName;
    }
}
return "randomName";
}

// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
String serverLocation) {

try {
    OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new 
File(serverLocation));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    outpuStream.flush();
    outpuStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**The problem is that i get this :

java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart"**

Answer (score -3):

I think you just remove header from RequestOptions, and your uploader will work

Comment: hay , am sorry but it still gives me the same problem

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: RESTEASY007550: Unable to get boundary for multipart

Comment: anyone got soln ?